# UIImagePickerController camera provides no URL

Tags: ios, swift

I've got an app I'm working on that up until a couple days ago only allowed someone to upload a photo from their photo library.  It works perfectly, and checks the metadata for GPS coordinates and makes a conditional comparison.

Now, however, I decided I'd like to let them snap a photo through the app, and have run into a snag.  The code that worked for the photo picking isn't working so well when using the camera.

Here's my original code for a button to upload a photo:

```
    @IBAction func pickPhoto(sender: AnyObject) {
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.SavedPhotosAlbum) {
        imageView.hidden = true

        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.SavedPhotosAlbum
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false

        presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

and then here's the UIImagePickerController:

```
    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {

    imageView.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage

    println("imagePickerController")

    let library = ALAssetsLibrary()

    let url: NSURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as! NSURL

    library.assetForURL(url, resultBlock: {
        (asset: ALAsset!) in

        if  asset.valueForProperty(ALAssetPropertyLocation) != nil {

            println("!= nil")
            let imageLongitude = (asset.valueForProperty(ALAssetPropertyLocation) as! CLLocation!).coordinate.longitude
            let imageLatitude = (asset.valueForProperty(ALAssetPropertyLocation) as! CLLocation!).coordinate.latitude

            println("imageLatitude = \(imageLatitude)")
            println("imageLongitude = \(imageLongitude)")

            println("Starting the Location check")
```

... and it goes on from there to do more checking.

I copied my pickPhoto button and turned it into a takePhoto button, like so:

```
    @IBAction func takePhoto(sender: AnyObject) {
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera) {
        imageView.hidden = true

        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false

        presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {

        notifyUser("No Camera", message: "This device doesn't have a camera!")
    }
}
```

and that opens up the camera and lets me take a photo.  However, when I use the photo, I immediately get a crash in the UIImagePickerController on this line:

```
let url: NSURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as! NSURL
```

I'm assuming that's because as a camera image, it's technically not saved anywhere, therefore it has no URL or path.

So my question is, how do I save the image (temporarily or in the camera roll), keeping the GPS metadata intact from the camera (assuming Location Services are active), so I can pass it along and have it play nice?

Answer (score 1):

edit:

**This post is outdated**

---

**Swift 2.x**

As you already noticed you need to save the file to disk to be able to get its url. You have to save it to your camera SavedPhotosAlbum or to your documents folder. You need also to save the image metadata info )UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata) as follow:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    
    print(info["UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"] ?? "NO IMAGE")
    print(info["UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"] ?? "NO URL")
    print(info["UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata"] ?? "NO METADATA")

    if let image = info["UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"] as? UIImage {
        ALAssetsLibrary().writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum(image.CGImage!, metadata: info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata]! as! [NSObject : AnyObject], completionBlock: { (url, error) -> Void in
            
            print("photo saved to asset")
            print(url)   // assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=CCC70B9F-748A-43F2-AC61-8755C974EE15&ext=JPG
            
            
            // you can load your UIImage that was just saved to your asset as follow
            let assetLibrary = ALAssetsLibrary()
            assetLibrary.assetForURL(url,
                resultBlock: { (asset) -> Void in
                    if let asset = asset {
                        let assetImage =  UIImage(CGImage:  asset.defaultRepresentation().fullResolutionImage().takeUnretainedValue())
                        print(assetImage)
                    }
                }, failureBlock: { (error) -> Void in
                if let error = error { print(error.description) }
            })

            if let error = error { print(error.description) }
            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  However, unless I'm doing something wrong the GPS data isn't passing through.  The photo is saving to the camera roll, and it finds the URL (great!), but the EXIF data printed to the console is missing the latitude and longitude info.  I have the app ask for location services permission when the app is in use.  Perhaps the camera doesn't automatically gather the GPS coordinates in a snapshot through another app?  I'm not sure.  If I go to my photos, I see my other photos listed with my city name.  The photos taken through the camera just now, though, don't have that.

Comment: forgot to put that tag there to let you know I replied.

Comment: ALAssets was deprecated in iOS9. You should use PHAsset instead of ALAsset